# Most efficient way to use strcat() with a string and int?

Tags: c, casting, int, concatenation, strcat

I'm try to concatenate to `char * rv` with the result of a function call that will return an `int`. `fib()` returns an int. The main problem I'm running into is that `strcat()`'s signature requires a `const char *` as it's second arg:

```
char * strcat ( char * destination, const char * source );
```

Here is a small sample of my code. `fib()` calculates the nth fibonacci number - in this case, the 7th fibonacci number.

```
char * rv;
int num;

rv = (char*)malloc(2048*sizeof(char));
num = 7;

...

strcat(rv, (const char *)itoa(fib(num), rv,10));
```

Obviously this is wrong and won't compile. What is the cleanest way to do this? Do I need another `char * var` to store the results of `itoa()` first, instead of using `rv`?

Thank you for any help you can provide!

Comment: off-topic, but may I suggest `rv = malloc(2048 * sizeof *rv)`; casting malloc's result is pointless in C, and the duplicated typename in the argument is just bitrot waiting to happen when you change types later.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need either an intermediate `char` array to print the number to before `strcat`ing, or you can directly `sprintf` the number to `rv`, but for that you need a pointer to the end,

```
char *rv = malloc(2048);
char *rv_end = rv;
...
rv_end += sprintf(rv_end, "%d", fib(num));
```

and also update the `rv_end` pointer when appending other things to the buffer.

(Thanks to [jthill](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1290731/jthill) for the improvement using the return value of `sprintf`.)

Comment: or `rv_end+=sprintf(rv_end,"%d",fib(num));`

Comment: Thank you for your response. Let's say I then wanted to append a literal string to rv after your code. Could I just use `sprintf(rv_end, "%s", "Hello World")`? And then update `rv_end += strlen(rv_end);` again?

Comment: @iaacp Yes, but it's even better to use jthill's improvement.

Comment: I just want to make sure when I concatenate to `rv` later, that I'm also updating `rv_end` properly. So if I used jthill's method for a literal string, I'd just use  `rv_end += sprintf(rv_end, "%s", "Hello!");`, correct?

Comment: Correct, @iaacp. But you could also just `strcat` (or `strcpy`) and add the length of the string. If you know the length beforehand, that will probably be more efficient than `sprintf`.

Answer (score 3):

Use [`snprintf()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf) to construct a buffer containing the `int` and then concatenate it to your `rv` buffer. Do **not** attempt to concatenate the existing content of `rv` in the same call to `snprintf()`:

```
snprintf(rv, 2048, "%s%d", rv, itoa(fib(num), rv,10)));
```

as this means the input and output buffers overlap which is undefined behaviour.

Also:

- `sizeof(char)` is guaranteed to be `1`
- see [Do I cast the result of malloc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc)

So the `malloc()` call would be:

```
rv = malloc(2048);
if (rv)
{
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could do this

```
sprintf(dest,"%s %d",rv,num);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
char * strcat ( char * destination, const char * source );
```

The "const" on source simply tells the compiler that the strcat function will not modify "source". Otherwise,

```
strcat(buffer, "hi");
```

would not be allowed.

This does not mean that your source must be constant, nor should it have the const modifier.

```
strcat(rv, (char *)itoa(fib(num), rv,10));
```

(no "const") is perfectly legal and should not generate any compiler warnings.

The only issue is that if you don't know the length of the source, you're opening yourself up to a buffer overflow. In this particular case, you can figure out how long the itoa return can be and size the destination accordingly. However, it's probably safer to us snprintf to control how large it is.